# Replacement for Seam 2 logger (or Seam3 Solder logger)

Tags: logging, cdi, seam, java-ee-7, deltaspike

I am moving on from Seam 2 to Java EE7 with CDI and some Apache Deltaspike extensions (using WildFly).

One thing that I am missing is a good logger that can format the message (e.g. like the String.format or MessageFormat).

I have seen that Seam 3 Solder logger was supposed to replace the Seam 2 logger however the development on Seam 3 Solder has been stopped and it was supposed to be taken over by Apache Deltaspike.

I've looked around but I couldn't find any logging API in Deltaspike.

Can someone point me in the right direction or suggest some good logger replacements which allow for message formatting?

Comment: Logger injection turned into an anti-pattern over time, because it's just an overhead without a real benefit. Everything else is up to your logging framework. There are so many out there so it shouldn't be a big deal to find one which fits for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the JBoss Logger (org.jboss.logging.Logger) offers both String.format and MessageFormat formatting.

I thought I was using that logger but Eclipse imported javax.util.logging.Logger instead which seems rather limited.

Comment: Hi @Ben can you elaborate on what your actual solution was? Did you end up using javax.util.logging.Logger?